# iOS WKWebview: Need to access websocket url on the webpage

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm facing an issue with the wkwebview where I need to handle the WebSocket URL. This same is working fine on the safari mobile browser but not on wkwebview.

I tried to search for the solution in the docs as well as google but no solution.

My Question:
Does the wkwebview support WebSocket? If yes, how can I enable it from the app side?
Is there a way to capture the wss:// URLs in wkwebview and might be making use of NSURLSession or SocketRocket to send back the data whatever is received?

What I have tried: In a demo app, I have made use of SocketRocket pod to work with the wss:// URL which I found on the webpage while inspecting, this helped in receiving a message from the socket and was also able to keep the connection open but not sure if anything changed on webpage.